# Can you execute a C# program on a computer with no Visual Studio or any other software?

Tags: c#

I have a working C# project that I would like to run on another computer.  The only problem is, the other computer doesn't have visual studio and I don't want to install any software on it.  Is it possible to run the .exe file or something so that I get the GUI without visual studio?

Comment: Of course this is possible. How do you think _any_ end-user Windows software works?

Comment: For a C# app, you'll need to have a suitable version of the .NET framework installed - that's about all.

Comment: I would like to know how to do this, please.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? I see this as a valid question (see the number of answers) for a beginner although the answer can be easily found in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking is if it's possible and if so, how. As others have mentioned, yes it's possible. It's the whole point. Your exe will be in the /bin/debug or /bin/release folder, depending on which mode you compiled in. Just send the .exe file to the other computer, and assuming it has an up to date version of Windows, it will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing it requires is the [.NET Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17113)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. VS will create an .msi file with a setup.exe for your users to install.  As long as the users have the correct dot net framework, the app will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Visual Studio to run the executable file, but the thing that it needs is that the right .NET Framework is installed, i.e. the version that the executable was compiled for.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0, so if I install that framework on the computer it can run it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, providing the other computer has a .net framework version installed that matches the requirements of your software, you can ship the application via creating an MSI with a setup or via sending the exe and any dlls required from within the bin directory created during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

C# is based on the Microsoft .NET Framework. 
There are multiple versions of the .NET framework. 1.0 up to 4.5

If you build your code in .net framework 2.0 then for your .exe file to work on another computer they must first install the .net framework 2.0 on that computer. Same for all other versions.

All the frameworks can be downloaded from the microsoft.com website.